# .NET6 NotifyIcon ContextMenu wont show

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, contextmenu, notifyicon

So I have built an app in .NET 6, and I'm able to get it to show the `NotifyIcon` in the Tray Area but the context menu (right-click) on the NotifyIcon just will not show up.

I built this code following [Implement a menu on tray icon for .NET 5/6 win forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895305/implement-a-menu-on-tray-icon-for-net-5-6-win-forms) (and then changing it so it was not using inline creation to see if it was causing this issue)

So the only thing i can think is that my Application does not have a Form so I'm running this code from the Program.cs file.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    private static ContextMenuStrip cms;

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("Assets/icon.ico");
        notifyIcon.Text = "Notify";

        cms = new ContextMenuStrip();

        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Reconnect", null, new EventHandler(Reconnect_Click)));
        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Quit", null, new EventHandler(Quit_Click), "Quit"));

        notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = cms;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                // do application background task
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    protected static void Reconnect_Click(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }

    protected static void Quit_Click(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Updated the ContextMenuStrip instance to be saved against the class not built in the Main Context/Scope

Comment: Unlikely to be your problem, but I suggest using a local variable to store your ContextMenuStrip while you populate it, instead of hitting the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the icon repeatedly.  Finish filling in your menu, and attach it to the icon afterward.

Comment: @BenVoigt as you thought it did not fix it but i have changed it and updated the code in the question.

Comment: There was a chance that something in the `ContextMenuStrip` property setter needed to see a menu that wasn't empty.  Guess not.  Either way your code's a little more efficient after the change.

Comment: By any chance, does the notification icon appear, but then get removed as soon as you put your mouse over it (even if you don't try to click on it)?

Comment: @BenVoigt no it appears I hover over it and the Title Displays, just if I click or Right Click the title will disappear until I move the mouse off and back on, but the icon stays there no problem.

Comment: And can you check in Task Manager that your program is still running?  As far as I can see, you're going to reach the end of `Main` and exit, even without a call to `Quit_Click`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251447/discussion-between-barkermn01-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: Don't forget to call Dispose() on notifyIcon before exiting. Sometimes Windows will hold on to the resource and leave the icon displayed in the tray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a message loop that handles Windows messages that are used in Windows applications to communicate between the operating system and the user interface of your application.

If you want an application without having a visible form but still run a message loop, use the `Application.Run` method with an `ApplicationContext` object. You do then also use the context to signal the end of the application.

Sample code:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    private static ContextMenuStrip cms;
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("Assets/icon.ico");
        notifyIcon.Text = "Notify";

        cms = new ContextMenuStrip();

        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Reconnect", null, new EventHandler(Reconnect_Click)));
        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
        cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Quit", null, new EventHandler(Quit_Click), "Quit"));

        notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = cms;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        // Create an ApplicationContext and run a message loop
        // on the context.
        context = new ApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);

        // Hide notify icon on quit
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
    }

    static void Reconnect_Click(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }

    static void Quit_Click(object? sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // End application though ApplicationContext
        context.ExitThread();
    }
}
```